# How to use pylint_django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, pylint

I am new to linting, using python 2.7 and pylint-django 0.7.2 for linting my django code.

`pylint --load-plugins pylint_django [..other options..] <path_to_your_sources>`

I didn't understand the **path_to_your_sources** in the above command? Do I've to give a .py file or the django directory?

I tried running with a .py file, getting the below error:

`ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings`

Can anyone please let me know what this error is saying and how to use pylint_django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this and you're all set.

Set Env Var:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_settings_file_path
For eg DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysettings.setting.base
```

Then run this command:

```
pylint --load-plugins=pylint_django --rcfile your_pylint_filename
Use * to run pylint for your whole project
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar issue like the one u mentioned, lemme share you my experience regarding how I fixed it :

- I have my project running on a work environment with "**virtualenvwrapper**" :

```
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ pwd
/home/mlazo/proyectos/project_textile
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV 
/home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile
```

- I was getting the error :

```
RuntimeError: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE required for resolving ForeignKey string references, see Usage section in README at https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/!
```

- First identify the main directory of my django project which is "**/home/mlazo/proyectos/project_textile/public/**".
- Then, test the pylint command via command line, if u can notice I set the parameter "**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**" which was required, more detailed information is explained here https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/ :

```
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.develop  /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/pylint  --reports=n --msg-template={path}:{line}:{msg_id}:{msg} --load-plugins pylint_django --disable=C0303 /home/mlazo/proyectos/project_textile/public/apps/grants/views.py
```

- The outcome was successfull gettings no errors at the end :

```
public/apps/grants/views.py:5:W0611:Unused redirect imported from django.shortcuts
public/apps/grants/views.py:9:W0611:Unused Http404 imported from django.http
public/apps/grants/views.py:19:W0611:Unused Value imported from django.db.models
public/apps/grants/views.py:19:W0611:Unused F imported from django.db.models
public/apps/grants/views.py:19:W0611:Unused Prefetch imported from django.db.models

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.37/10 (previous run: 8.37/10, +0.00)
```

- Once the command is working fine, I started to think how to set the variable "**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**" automatically once I place on my working environment, and I checked that everytime you place on your working environment there are available hooks (**{pre,post}activate** and **{pre,post}deactivate**) that can be executed :

```
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ ls $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/*activate
/home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/activate      /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/postdeactivate  /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/predeactivate
/home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/postactivate  /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/preactivate
```

- so I proceed to add the following commands in the following files :

```
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ cat /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/postactivate 
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after this virtualenv is activated.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.develop


(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ cat /home/mlazo/.virtualenvs/project_textile/bin/predeactivate
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced before this virtualenv is deactivated.
unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

- finally, everytime u place in ur working env you will set the "**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**" variable, and everytime u leave the environment it will be destroyed:

```
mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ workon project_textile
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
settings.develop
(project_textile) mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ deactivate 
mlazo@mlazo-pc:~/proyectos/project_textile$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

I really wish it would be helpful for anybody that is dealing with a similar incident.

Best regards,